# Error connecting to server in a file

Tags: c, linux, sockets

I have a big problem. Let us suppose that we have a txt file (named `file_config.txt`) such us this:

```
192.168.1.4 65000
www.google.com 80
```

They are two server.

I have a server that contact this server in this way:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

...;

if ((f = fopen(file_name,"r"))!=NULL) { /* file is present */

       /* I send the file to the client */

}else{ /* file isn't present so I have to contact the server in the txt file */

       config = fopen(file_config,"r"); 

       line = 0;

       flag = 0;

       while (fgets(file_line,MAXLINE,config)!=NULL) {

                        line ++;

                        r = sscanf(file_line,"%s %s",server,port);

                        flag = Client(server,port,rbuffer,socket);

                        if (flag == 1) {

                            break; 
                        }
       }

       fclose(config); 

       if (flag == 0) {
           Send(s,errore,strlen(errore));
           break; 
       }                   

 }

}
```

And here the Client function:

```
int Client(char *server, char *porta,char *comando, int file_descriptor){

    const int MAXBUF = 7;
    const int MAX = 70;
    char termine[] = "QUIT\r\n";
    char indirizzo_IP[24];
    struct in_addr indirizzo_server; 
    struct sockaddr_in indirizzo_remoto;
    struct hostent *h;
    uint16_t porta_server; 
    char resoconto[MAX]; 
    char *buffer; 
    int s;
    int i;
    int flag;
    long bytes;
    int n;

    /* porta del server */

    if(sscanf(porta,"%" SCNu16,&porta_server)!=1){

        printf("Errore durante la lettura della porta dal file\n");

        return 0; /* equivale a file non trovato */
    }

    /* verifico se server è un indirizzo IP oppure se è un CNAME */

    flag = 0;

    for (i=0; i<strlen(server); i++) {
        if ((isalpha(server[i]))==0) {
            flag = 1;
        }
    }

    /* indirizzo Server */

    if(flag == 0){ /* server è un indirizzo IP */

        inet_aton(server,&indirizzo_server);

        /* allocazione della struttura indirizzo_remoto */

        memset((char *)&indirizzo_remoto,0,sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));

        /* preparazione indirizzo del server */

        indirizzo_remoto.sin_family = AF_INET;

        indirizzo_remoto.sin_port = htons(porta_server); /* porta su cui è in ascolto il server */

        indirizzo_remoto.sin_addr = indirizzo_server; /* indirizzo al quale il server esegue : indirizzo_remoto.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("192.168.1.4"); */


    }else{ /* server è un Canonical NAME */

        h = gethostbyname(server);

        if( h == NULL ){
            printf("Errore");
            return 0; /* passo al server successivo */
        }

        inet_aton(h->h_addr_list[0],&indirizzo_server);

        /* allocazione della struttura indirizzo_remoto */

        memset((char *)&indirizzo_remoto,0,sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));

        /* preparazione indirizzo del server */

        indirizzo_remoto.sin_family = AF_INET;

        indirizzo_remoto.sin_port = htons(porta_server); /* porta su cui è in ascolto il server */

        indirizzo_remoto.sin_addr = indirizzo_server; /* indirizzo al quale il server esegue : indirizzo_remoto.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("192.168.1.4"); */

        printf("Il nome '%s' ha indirizzo IP '%s' e porta '%d'\n",server,inet_ntoa(indirizzo_remoto.sin_addr),ntohs(indirizzo_remoto.sin_port));
    }


    /* creazione del socket */

    s = Socket();

    /* connessione con il socket remoto - quello sul server */

    if((connect(s,(struct sockaddr *) &indirizzo_remoto,sizeof(indirizzo_remoto)))==-1){
        Stampa_errore("connect() errore");
    }

    printf("connect() fatta");

    /* Invio al server il comando */

    Send(s,comando,strlen(comando));

    /* Ricevo risposta dal server */

    Recv(s,resoconto,MAXBUF);

    if (strcmp(resoconto,"+OK\r\n")==0) { /* il server in questine non ha il file */

        /* Aspetto di ricevere la dimensione del file */

        n = recv(s,&bytes,sizeof(bytes),0); /* USARE LA FUNZIONE DEL PROFESSORE */

        printf("recv: %d - bytes: %ld\n",n,bytes);

        /*if () {
            return 0; /* vado alla riga dopo */
        //}

        /* invio al client da dimensione */

        send(file_descriptor,&bytes,sizeof(bytes),0);

        bytes = ntohs(bytes);

        /* faccio l'allocazione dinamica */

        buffer = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*bytes);

        if (buffer==NULL) {

            printf("Memoria non disponibile per ricevere il file\n");
            exit(-1);

        }

        read(s,buffer,bytes); /* ATTENZIONE: provare a sostituire con recv */

        /* invio il file al client */

        Send(file_descriptor,buffer,bytes);

        /* fare free */

        free(buffer);

        /* invio QUIT\r\n al server */

        Send(s,termine,strlen(termine));

        /* chiudo il socket */

        close(s);

        return 1; /* = 1 file trovato / = 0 file non trovato */

    }else{
        printf("Il server non ha compreso il comando\n");
        Close(s);
        printf("Socket chiuso\n");
        return 0; /* analogo a file non trovato su questo server */

    }

}
```

It doesn't work:

If the first server in the txt file has the file the code works.
But if the first server hasn't the file the Client method stop after Socket (Socket is the last action that goes good).

P.S.:

I know that I can't contact www.google.com and ask a file with my own protocol. But I have insert it only for see if the resolution of the canonical name work correctly.

Comment: where it doesen't work? what is the current and expected behaviour ?

Comment: I update the question with an edit action. Sorry!

Comment: The Client has the comment in italian language, if there are same problems I translate them

Comment: What does `Socket()` do ?

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
inet_aton(h->h_addr_list[0],&indirizzo_server);
```

is wrong. `h_addr_list` is not a list of strings in the format that `inet_aton` expects. It's not even a list of strings at all. It's a list of addresses ready to be copied directly into the appropriate field of the `struct sockaddr_*`.

The `char **h_addr_list` in `struct hostent` should be treated as `void **`, which is what it would be if it hadn't been designed before ANSI C gave us `void`. A generic pointer is used because `gethostby*` supports (at least theoretically) arbitrary address families.

In the case of `h_addrtype==AF_INET`, each `h_addr_list[n]` is a pointer to a `struct in_addr`, so you can just say `indirizzo_server = *(struct in_addr *)h_addr_list[0];` and all will be well.